# How to provide predefined data structure to Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to put a default structure for some data in Firebase Database.

I'm developing a chat application using Firebase with a static list of chat groups.

There is a way to manually push the list of groups (with all the data fields needed already filled) or some others predefined data without using a mobile app or a website?

Answer (score 2):

You can create the data structure as a JSON file and them import that JSON file into your Firebase Console.

Alternatively you can import the JSON file from a command line, using the [Firebase CLI's `database:set` command](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/#database_commands).